# Using DOM PHP Parse child contents

Tags: php, html

```
<h2>
<strong>
<a href="http://www.linkedin.com/pub/rom-agustin/0/111/947" title="Rom Agustin">
  <span class="given-name">Rom</span>
  <span class="family-name">Agustin</span>
</a>
</strong>
</h2>
```

So i need to parse the two span classes and store them each in a variable.

span.given-name = $given_name

span.family-name = $family_name

Right now my code is :

```
foreach($vcard as $items):
    $names = $items->getElementsByTagName('h2');
    $name = $names->item(0)->nodeValue;
    echo $name; //Rom Agustin
endforeach;
```

How to properly separated those two? or how can i just target the class? I've read the DOM in php.net but there is no GetElementbyClass. Tried explode, very messy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net, which makes it a breeze, with http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm#section_create explaining how to work from plain string.

```
$htmltext = "...your snippet...";
$html = str_get_html($htmltext);
foreach($html->find("span") as $span) {
  // use $span here!
}
```

Comment: Is there any other way from the built-in functions? :)

Comment: there's no good built in HTML parsing that I'm aware of. And simpledom is literally just download file, drop into same dir, include file. After that you're basically doing jQuery calls, in PHP, which is bloody convenient.

Comment: Thanks! Will keep this library handy :)